# android login using POST method REST API

Tags: android, api, rest, post

I am a beginner in android development and I am working on a android application with REST api for login. I have to use POST method for login. 
After going through the docs and sites, i tried to implement the below code, but It's giving "invalid post request" every time. I tried to debugge but wasn't able to find the reason. Can someone please help me with link to understand how can i implement this. 
We have to pass the JSON paramter ***{"username": "abc@test.com","password": "abctest"}*** (i guess that is general)

> ```
>           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>             HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://beta.m-adaptive.com/login");
>             BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("username", paramUsername);
>             BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("password", paramPassword);
>             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>             nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
>             nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePair);
>             try {
>                 UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
>                 httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
>                 try {
>                     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
>                     InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
>                     InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
>                     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
>                     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
>                     String bufferedStrChunk = null;
>                     while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
>                         stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
>                     }
>                     return stringBuilder.toString();
>                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 } catch (IOException e) {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             return null;
>         }
>         @Override
>         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>             super.onPostExecute(result);
>             if(result.equals("working")){
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }else{
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST request...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }
> ```

Comment: try postman client to chk it

Comment: one more thing when i hit the url given above it not working in broswer make sure it woking service

Comment: `BasicNameValuePair` != `JSON`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, The link is working, i tested it on Advance REST Client, but now clear. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps :

```
class PlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPst = new HttpPost(

                "yout_url");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(

                2);

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                        "apple@gmail.com"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "apple"));

                httpPst.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

                HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpPst);

                String str = convertStreamToString(
                        httpRes.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                Log.i("mlog", "outfromurl" + str);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass JSON as your only parameter, you have to use StringEntity instead of UrlEncodedFormEntity and send the whole string, like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://beta.m-adaptive.com/login");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(YOUR JSON));
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    ...
```